# mysql - insert if not exist

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to insert to my DB table new row only if the same row details (except 'mode' column) is NOT exist in the last 10 results (according to the createDate column (timestamp type).

I'm getting this error:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

My query:

```
INSERT INTO user_last_view (1, 'res', 2, 'edit') 
SELECT (userID, page, refID, `mode`) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user_last_view WHERE userID=1 AND page='res' AND refID=2 ORDER BY createDate DESC LIMIT 10)
```

userID, refID -> int

page, mode ->varchar

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE user_last_view` is the preferred way of showing structure. Is the combination of `userID, page, refID`  unique? or something/more/less/different?

Comment: Hi, no. i don't have unique column in this table. just indexs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the list after the table name you must list the target columns, not the values. The values go into the list after `SELECT`. And a `FROM`-less `SELECT` doesn't seem to work in MySQL when there's a `WHERE` clause. You can use `FROM dual`. So syntactically you would need to write:

```
INSERT INTO user_last_view
            (userid,
             page,
             refid,
             mode) 
           SELECT 1,
                  'res',
                  2, 'edit'
                  FROM dual
                  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                           FROM user_last_view
                                           WHERE userid = 1
                                                 AND page = 'res'
                                                 AND refid = 2
                                           ORDER BY createdate
                                           DESC LIMIT 10);
```

But that won't do what you want because it gets the last ten *matching* rows, not the last ten in general and then checks if one matches. Instead of directly selecting from the table, select from a derived table that gets the last ten rows regardless of a match and then checks for a match within those.

```
INSERT INTO user_last_view
            (userid,
             page,
             refid,
             mode) 
           SELECT 1,
                  'res',
                  2, 'edit'
                  FROM dual
                  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                           FROM (SELECT ulv.userid,
                                                        ulv.page,
                                                        ulv.refid
                                                        FROM user_last_view ulv
                                                        ORDER BY ulv.createdate
                                                        DESC LIMIT 10) x
                                           WHERE x.userid = 1
                                                 AND x.page = 'res'
                                                 AND x.refid = 2);
```

Comment: Hi, i'll try that. thanks. but what does "dual" mean (`FROM dual`)?

Comment: @roi: `dual` is a special (pseudo)  table that is always there (doesn't need  to be created, cannot be dropped) and contains only ever exactly one row.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is the unnecessary SELECT (userID, page, refID, `mode`). You are already specifying values to insert. I think you need something like:

`INSERT INTO user_last_view VALUES (1, 'res', 2, 'edit') WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user_last_view WHERE userID=1 AND page='res' AND refID=2 ORDER BY createDate DESC LIMIT 10)`

Comment: I think that you can't write this syntax - `2 errors were found during analysis.

Unexpected token. (near "WHERE" at position 56)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "WHERE" at position 56)`

Comment: No, a `VALUES` and a `WHERE` clause cannot be used together like this. One'd either need an `INSERT ... SELECT ... WHERE` like in the OP or subqueries in the `VALUES` clause that then have the `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: @sticky bit - Yup, you're right. Thanx for the details